# речевая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нет ли здесь речевой ошибки?

В качестве примера, иллюстрирующего верность моей мысли, хочу привести героя из книги "Маугли".

Спасибо!

Comment: Да, это речевая ошибка. В качестве примера нельзя привести героя.  Возможно, если вы приедете контекст, мы исправим ошибку.

Comment: @Серж Что если так: "Герои некоторых книг живут в джунглях. В качестве примера...".

Comment: Да, верно. Всё зависит от контекста.  Что за мысль – вот что нужно знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если судить строго, то здесь *лишний предлог* "из". Правильная сочетаемость *беспредложна*: **герой книги** - то же, что **её** *главный персонаж*. Смысл здесь переносный, но предлог был бы уместен, если бы книга была о нескольких "героях" в буквальном смысле (тогда это был бы *один из* персонажей, описанных в книге как **герои**). Считать это *речевой ошибкой* или *стилистической недоработкой* - дело субъективное (корректор мог бы поправить, а в разговоре и даже на лекции это осталось бы незамеченным).

Если придираться, можно и двусмысленность найти: неужели в качестве примера *за руку приведет* живого героя для подтверждения мысли "герои ещё не перевелись в мире" (или цинично аниматора наймёт)? Но носитель языка не задержится на фантастическом смысле и поймёт текст однозначно.

Иными словами, исправлять или нет, зависит от значимости высказывания.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, какой-нибудь босс-грамотей может выпустить книгу, где он зарегламентирует такие ситуации как «речевые ошибки», но автор подобного предложения всегда может сказать, что это такой фигуральный прием. К тому же у слова «приводить» есть устоявшееся в языке переносное значение. Мы же говорим: «Я привел пример», «Я привел аргумент» и тд. Если можно приводить пример, то почему нельзя приводить героя в качестве примера? Нет, это никакая не речевая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

```
Привести пример = Предъявить пример ≈ Озвучить пример.
```

Применяем и получаем очевидный бред:

```
Хочу озвучить Васю как пример хорошего человека.
```

Но исходная фраза звучит нормально. Видимо, не стоит ждать от языка математической строгости. Если посмотреть, то можно найти много таких ошибок в языке. Например: "Какой из пунктов правильный?" вместо "Который из пунктов правильный?".

Comment: Автор ответа  не любит  бред и фантазии, но зато очень любит подстановки и перестановки в качестве неопровержимого доказательства.  Математической строгости нужно ждать от математики, я языку нужна точность и выразительность, причем во всех стилях речи. Неубедительный ответ.